# How to use different function to same name button?

Tags: jquery

I want use the same name to my buttons, but i would like to click a button and show the solution for the button. For example i click on the first button(Task) show just the first solution(Solution). I would like to do because i want a lot of task - solution pairs. Thanks for the answers.

Here is my code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="task">
        <button>Task</button>
        <div class="solution">Solution</div>
    </div>
    <div class="task">
        <button>Task2</button>
        <div class="solution">Solution2</div>
    </div>
</body>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
            $(".solution").slideToggle("slow");
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery's [`.siblings`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) function:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("button").click(function() {
     $(this).siblings(".solution").slideToggle("slow");
   });

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="task">
  <button>Task</button>
  <div class="solution">Solution</div>
</div>
<div class="task">
  <button>Task2</button>
  <div class="solution">Solution2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to reference the specific button clicked with `$(this)`:

```
$('button').click(function () {
  $(this).siblings('.solution').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

This will create a universal rule that can apply to any number of button-solution-pairs, however you should make sure that this combination of classes doesn't appear anywhere else on your website, probably the easiest by limiting the scope to a certain parent class.

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse to the parent element and find the `.solution` within it:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("button").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find('.solution').slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="task">
        <button>Task</button>
        <div class="solution">Solution</div>
    </div>
    <div class="task">
        <button>Task2</button>
        <div class="solution">Solution2</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This works, but is just a more complicated way of achieving what `siblings()` does

Comment: You are correct, however this code **will work** even if the `.solution` element is inside another wrapper-element. The `siblings()` solution will not work in such case.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [jQuery next](https://api.jquery.com/next/):

```js
$(function () {
  $("button").click(function () {
    $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<div class="task">
    <button>Task</button>
    <div class="solution">Solution</div>
</div>
<div class="task">
    <button>Task2</button>
    <div class="solution">Solution2</div>
</div>
```